# Why is the mvn command not found in this declarative jenkins pipeline script?

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I got this example from https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#tools

Pipeline Script:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {
        maven 'apache-maven-3.3.9' 
    }
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

apache-maven-3.3.9 is defined in my Global Tool Configuration.

The output of the script however is

```
Started by user *************
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] node
Running on SRV-CI-MADE-UNIX in /home/jenkins/workspace/*************
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Tool Install)
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] envVarsForTool
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Example)
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] envVarsForTool
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ mvn --version
/home/jenkins/workspace/*************@tmp/durable-d4209a18/script.sh: line 1: mvn: command not found
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
[BFA] Scanning build for known causes...
[BFA] No failure causes found
[BFA] Done. 0s
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE
```

Why is the mvn command not found?

I know there are apparently other ways to do this, but this is the example from the Jenkins documentation itself...

Answer (score 0):

It is the correct example (I tested it also), but it's working if you have only `master` node.

I think that you've just configured your Maven tool in `Global Tool Configuration` for `master` node, but I see that you executed your job on `SRV-CI-MADE-UNIX` node, and for this node you need also provide a correct Maven configuration.

So, to fix the issue I suppose that you need to do these steps:

1. provide the correct agent (instead of `agent any`) in pipeline configuration (e.g. `master` or `SRV-CI-MADE-UNIX`) for which Maven tool is configured;
2. install Maven on the specified node in the same directory as you configured in `Global Tool Configuration` or add your specific Maven tool location for this node in `Manage Jenkins -> Manage Nodes -> <YOUR_NODE> -> Configure -> Node Properties -> Tool Locations`

Comment: Well, my master is Windows, the slave is UNIX... So configuring the same directory is not possible.

Comment: So, specify the right agent and try to add Maven tool location in `Node Properties`.